# Twitter Bootstrap Floating Off Canvas Side Bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen lots of examples around of using an off-canvas sidebar such as here http://bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/off-canvas-sidebar

In this example when the screen is resized small, the main content area is pushed off to the right by the width of the shown sidebar.

Is there a way to not do this and instead float the sidebar over the main content area? This would also remove the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would switch the set the `active` position of the navbar to `left:0` so that is floats over the page content.

```
row-offcanvas-left.active .navbar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    width:40%;
    background-color:#eee;
    border:0 solid #ddd;
    border-left-width:1px;
  }
```

Here's an example: http://www.bootply.com/I9BrKZj1PE